# MongoDB pipeline optimisation, is it good practice to set temporary field for further stages?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some questions about a mongodb pipeline!

**The situation**

I'm making a mongodb pipeline to increment users connection count but also building up a "streak" system that increments every time a user connects at least once a day (Not the same day but between +24h and +48h).

All the connection stats data are stored on each user document in an object named `connection` that follows the following interface `IUserStatsData`:

```js
interface IUserStatsData
{
    /** The total counter of the stat */
    total?: number
    /** The last time the counter has been incremented */
    last?: Date
    /** Streak data of the stat */
    streak?: IUserStatsStreakData
}

interface IUserStatsStreakData
{
    /** Actual streak */
    actual?: number
    /** Max streak */
    max?: number
    /** Last time a streak was incremented or reset for time based streaks ONLY */
    last?: Date
}
```

If the last time the user had a connection streak increment or reset is older than a day and newer than two days, then I increment the actual streak.

If the actual streak is greater than the max streak, I set the max to actual.

To keep track of the previous `connection.streak.actual` value, I store it on a temporary field named `connection.streak.prev`. I use it on further stage to know if the actual streak value has changed, then I unset it at the end of the following pipeline.

**My questions are**

Is it ok to store temporary values like this?

I red about `$let` but can I use it in this case (I tried but failed)?

This pipeline works but I'm a mongodb newcomer there's certainly better ways to achieve this, would you share an advice of yours?

**The pipeline**

```js
{$set: {
    "connection.total": {$sum: ["$connection.total", 1]},
    "connection.last": new Date(),
    "connection.streak.prev": {$ifNull: ["$connection.streak.actual", 0]},
    "connection.streak.actual": {$cond: [
        {$lt: [{$subtract: [new Date(), "$connection.streak.last"]}, 3600 * 1000 * 24]},
        {$ifNull: ["$connection.streak.actual", 0]},
        {$cond: [
            {$lt: [{$subtract: [new Date(), "$connection.streak.last"]}, 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 2]},
            {$sum: ["$connection.streak.actual", 1]},
            0
        ]}
    ]}
}},
{$set: {
    "connection.streak.last": {$cond: [
        {$or: [
            {$not: ["$connection.streak.last"]},
            {$ne: ["$connection.streak.actual", "$connection.streak.prev"]}
        ]},
        new Date(),
        "$connection.streak.last"
    ]}
}},
{$set: {
    "connection.streak.max": {$cond: [
        {$gt: ["$connection.streak.actual", {$ifNull: ["$connection.streak.max", 0]}]},
        "$connection.streak.actual",
        "$connection.streak.max"
    ]}
}},
{$unset: ["connection.streak.prev"]}
```

Sounds like a big pipeline to me.

Thanks for your time helping me to improve my mongodb knowledge!

Comment: (1) In general, I suggest using `$addFields` and `$project` _instead of_ `$set` and `$unset`. Its just convention to use `$set` and `$unset` for Updates with Aggregation Pipeline. (2) You can avoid using the extra stage for `{$unset: ["connection.streak.prev"]}`, by using `project` in the _prior_ stage to it. Please refer the MongoDB manual for proper usage and examples.

Comment: When you have to work with date values, have a look at new [Date Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I red about $dateDiff but it is available since 5.0 and I'm running 4.4 at the moment. Is that what you are thinking of? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes, you would have less code to write.